# PyEphem Angle Clarification

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

I'd just like to make sure I understand what PyEphem is doing with angles.

Let's say I have an observer at 30° S, 60° W looking at the sky today at noon.
So I do:

```
obs = ephem.Observer()
obs.lat, obs.lon = '-30', '-60'
obs.date = '2012/6/22 12:00:00'
```

Now I want to find which part of the celestial sphere (in RA and declination) the observer sees when looking at a certain azimuth and altitude. I can do:

```
obs.radec_of(az,alt)
```

Here is where I'm confused. From what I understand, PyEphem works with all angles as radians, so I should put `az` and `alt` in as radians. Is it the case, then, that 0° altitude is the horizon, 90° altitude is directly overhead, and -90° is pointing straight into the ground? In which case, does PyEphem consider 95° altitude to be the same as 85° or does it roll over into -85°?

Also, if the observer wants to look at the south celestial pole, is this the correct code?

```
az = float( ephem.degree('180') )
alt = float( ephem.degree('30') )
ra, dec = obs.radec_of(az,alt)
```

Or should the altitude be -30°?

Comment: 12:00 in UTC does not correspond to noon at 30° S, 60° W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of altitude and azimuth sounds correct! The south celestial pole indeed lies 30° above the southern horizon for someone at 30° south latitude, exactly as you describe.

But there are one or two fixes that we can make to your code.

First, a misspelling. The function you are looking for that converts degrees to radians is named `ephem.degrees()` (note that plural) — if you try calling `ephem.degree` as a function, then you will get the exception:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

because `ephem.degree` is actually the floating-point number 0.0174532925199 because that is how many radians are in a degree. And you cannot call a floating-point number as though as it is a function! Fixing that, we get correct and working code for your example:

```
az = float(ephem.degrees('180'))
alt = float(ephem.degrees('30'))
ra, dec = obs.radec_of(az,alt)
print ra, dec

→ 12:30:10.05 -89:53:54.7
```

But we can make the code even simpler!

First, the return value of `ephem.degrees()` is already a floating-point number, so the `float()` call around it is not actually necessary; you can just say:

```
az = ephem.degrees('180')
alt = ephem.degrees('30')
```

and those two values are just fine as the arguments to `radec_of()`. In fact, you can do even better: because the `radec_of()` function knows that azimuth and altitude are traditionally given in degrees, you can just hand the strings to the function itself and it will assume that the numbers inside of your strings are written in degrees. So we can eliminate the `az` and `alt` variables entirely if we want and just say:

```
ra, dec = obs.radec_of('180', '30')
```

Finally, you might wonder why the RA and declination we got back were not quite *exactly* at the south pole, even though they were close.

The first reason is that PyEphem takes account of atmospheric refraction, which boosts the apparent altitude of an object above the horizon at low altitudes. If we tell the `Observer` object to ignore atmospheric effects (by telling it there is no air where we live — atmospheric pressure zero), then the return value will be even closer to the south pole:

```
obs.pressure = 0
ra, dec = obs.radec_of('180', '30')
print ra, dec

→ 12:24:25.48 -89:55:15.9
```

That, obviously, gets us closer. There are one or two issues left involving precession and perhaps even nutation, that we need to tackle to actually drive the declination down to a full –90°, but I will have to look at them in the morning when I can visualize angles better!

Answer (score 4):

To answer your other question: an altitude like 95° *neither* is simply considered simply the same as 85°, *nor* does PyEphem consider it to be way down below our feet near the nadir at –85° altitude. Instead, it thinks of 95° as meaning “go all the way up the line of azimuth that you are following — up, up, up, until finally you reach the zenith and are at 90° — and then *keep going* five degrees over into the other side of the sky, bringing you five degrees down the completely opposite line of azimuth.”

So if you ask about the point at azimuth and altitude (15°, 95°) then PyEphem will think of that as going all the way up the 15° line and then going even further so that you start going back *down* the 195° azimuth line on the other side of the zenith. So the “normalized” name for the azimuth and altitude you are talking about is (195°, 90° – 5°) = (195°, 85°).